# ANSI C S-Linked List - deleteLast() not functioning correctly

Tags: c, linked-list, c89

When trying to run my deleteLast() function twice (to get an empty list) on a linked list with two nodes, I am running into a problem. The code compiles and runs, but when I call traverse() on my empty linked list, I get an infinite while loop, and I cannot determine why.

Oddly enough, if I call deleteFirst() twice instead of deleteLast(), the program runs and terminates properly.

Below is the code for my methods:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct NODE
{
    struct NODE *link;
    int value;
};

typedef struct NODE Node;



/* Deletes the first item in the list and returns next item */
Node *deleteFirst(Node **ptrToHeadPtr)
{
    Node *current;

    // If list is empty do nothing
    if (*ptrToHeadPtr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    else
    {
        current = *ptrToHeadPtr;
        *ptrToHeadPtr = current->link;
        free(current);
    }

    return *ptrToHeadPtr;
}

/* Inserts a new Node to the end of the list and returns it */
Node *insertLast(Node **ptrToHeadPtr, int val)
{
    Node *current, *lastNode;
    lastNode = (Node *)malloc( sizeof (Node) );

    // Check if malloc was successful
    if(!lastNode) return NULL;

    lastNode->value = val;
    lastNode->link = NULL;

    if (*ptrToHeadPtr == NULL)
        *ptrToHeadPtr = lastNode;

    else
    {
        current = *ptrToHeadPtr;

        // Walk to the end of the list
        while(current->link != NULL)
            current = current->link;

        // Insert new item at the end of the list
        current->link = lastNode;
    }
    return lastNode;
}

/* Deletes the last Node in the list and returns*/
Node *deleteLast(Node **ptrToHeadPtr)
{
    Node *current, *previous;

    /* If list is empty do nothing */
    if (*ptrToHeadPtr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    current = *ptrToHeadPtr;
    previous = NULL;

    /* If list has one item delete it and return NULL */
    if (current->link == NULL)
    {
        *ptrToHeadPtr == NULL;
        free(current);
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Walk to the end of the list */
        while (current->link != NULL)
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current->link;
        }

        previous->link = NULL;
        free(current);
        return previous;
    }       
}


/* Traverses the list, printing the value of each Node */
void traverse(Node*p)
{
    while( p!= NULL )
    {
        printf("%d ",p->value);
        p=p ->  link;
    }
}

/* Walks through the linked list, freeing memory of each Node */
void freeList(Node *p)
{
    Node *temp;
    while( p != NULL )
    {
        temp = p;
        p = p-> link;
        free(temp);
    }
}


int main()
{
    Node *headPtr = NULL;

    insertLast( &headPtr, 33 );
    insertLast( &headPtr, 35 );

    traverse(headPtr);
    printf("\n");

    deleteFirst ( &headPtr );
    traverse(headPtr);
    printf("\n");

    deleteLast ( &headPtr );

    traverse(headPtr);
    freeList(headPtr);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Add the correct tag. The `C` tag is for standard C, not C89/90. Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. We are no debugging service.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled (`-Wall` for gcc or clang) and fix all the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

In your deleteLast() function (They're called functions in C, just so you know, not methods. Not trying to sound snarky.)

```
    /* If list has one item delete it and return NULL */
if (current->link == NULL)
{
    *ptrToHeadPtr == NULL; // CHANGE THIS TO =, NOT ==
    free(current);
    return NULL;
}
```

edit: Just like the above poster suggested, you should definitely compile with -Wall (the W is case sensitive, must be capitalized.) It would have caught this.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tags / names - but thank you for pointing it out so that I know what to do moving forward.

I've been compiling with -gcc which apparently did not catch it, so thanks for telling me about -Wall.